# How can I prevent my hands from knife cut during cooking?

Tags: food, personal-care, safety, knives

I am not a expert cook and facings too much difficulties during cooking . One of them is knife cuts. Mostly I cut my fingers. How can I prevent my hands from knife cut during cooking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is the "claw" technique. Have your fingernails point inward away from the blade and have the knuckles in contact with your knife. Do not raise your blade high enough so that your knuckles lose contact with the knife.

Comment: This. If you don't want to cut your fingertips, don't expose them.

Answer (score 4):

A general rule of handling blades of any sort is to cut away from yourself (including pointing it away from your hand and your fingers), in case the blade slips.

(You may want to ask the question on the Seasoned Advise SE; if there are any tips specifically for cooking, there surely are people there who know them.)

Otherwise there are some things they sell that you can put on your fingers to prevent yourself from cutting them while chopping.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid knife cuts by the precautions

1. Since you are beginner, cut in slow speed.
2. Your hands should not be oily so that the vegetable like tomato can slip and there are chances to get a cut. Keep tissues to avoid oily hands.
3. stay at distance of two to three feet from burner during cutting.
4. place on which you are setting vegetables to cut them should be flat.
5. Apply the required force only which an item needed to get cut; over-forcing or over-speed can cause a serious cut.
6. Knife should be sharp enough so that you will be able to cut vegetable by gentle motion.